# How can I use multiple "filter"' with tweepy?

Tags: python, filter, tweepy

I'm a beginner on Python and am having an issue that I can't resolve on my first project using the API Tweepy. Here's the code :

```
count = 0
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = "#mykeyword follow -filter:retweets filter:verified", tweet_mode='extended').items(10):
    count+=1
    print(f" Tweet n°{count}, Utilisateur = {tweet.user.name}, Tweet = {tweet.full_text}")
```

I would like this script to return the 10 last tweets containing the hashtag "mykeyword" and "follow" from verified accounts, filtering out every retweets.
It works well when I keep either "-filter:retweets" or "filter:verified" but returns no results if I keep both, even though there should be some results.
I have already tested some answers I found on Stackoverflow but most of them are quite outdated and the Tweepy documentation doesn't seem to cover my problem.

Does anyone have an idea about this matter ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this convention

```
filter:media AND -filter:retweets
```

and it worked for my use case.

Comment: Is there a way to filter out users I've blocked?